# How to return key if a given string matches the keys value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to dictionaries, and i'm trying to find out how to return a key if a given string matches the keys value in a dictionary.

Example:

```
dict = {"color": (red, blue, green), "someothercolor": (orange, blue, white)}
```

I want to return `color` and `someothercolor`, if the key's value contains `blue`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `red` supposed to be `"red"`, and similarly for `blue` and `green`? And what have you tried?

Comment: Side note: Don't use `dict` for your dictionary name, as it is a `builtin`.  Use something more descriptive like `colors` or `color_dict`

Comment: @RoryDaulton I haven't really tried anything worth posting here.

Comment: You basically used the dictionary the wrong way. They are made to lookup a value by a key, not the othervway around. If you just have to do it once, the rather expensive solutions beliw might be ok, but if you have to run many of these lookups in a large dictionary, you might want to have a second dictionary the has the values you are looking for as keys and the list of keys from the first dictionary that contain these colors as values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may write *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> my_dict = {"color": ("red", "blue", "green"), "someothercolor": ("orange", "blue", "white")}

>>> my_color = "blue"
>>> [k for k, v in my_dict.items() if my_color in v]
['color', 'someothercolor']
```

Note: Do not use `dict` as variable because [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is built-in data type in Python

Comment: In order to speed up your code you should use a set instead of a tuple if possible. @Jonas

Comment: @DennyWeinberg for tuples this small, the time it takes to change it would be orders of magnitude greater than the extra time it takes to run.

Comment: I mean for the input, not the output.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is (without comprehension expression)

```
my_dict = {"color": ("red", "blue", "green"), "someothercolor": ("orange", "blue", "white")}
solutions = []
my_color = 'blue'
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if my_color in value:
        solutions.append(key)
```