# Looking for words in string that matches the values in a dictionary, then return key in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, dictionary

I've been trying to iterate through strings in a pandas dataframe to look for a certain set of words and here I've been successful.

However, I realised that I didn't just want to find words but also look at the semantics of a word and group together a certain set of words that bare the same meaning as my main keyword.

I stumbled upon the following question **[How to return key if a given string matches the keys value in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495713/how-to-return-key-if-a-given-string-matches-the-keys-value-in-a-dictionary)** which is exactly what I want to do but unfortunately can’t get it to work in a pandas dataframe.

Below is one of the solutions which can be found in the link:

```
my_dict = {"color": ("red", "blue", "green"), "someothercolor":("orange", "blue", "white")}

solutions = []

my_color = 'blue'

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if my_color in value:
        solutions.append(key)
```

Outputs:

```
color
```

**My data frame:**

Now I have a data frame where I would like to iterate through df[’Name’] to find a value and then I want to add the key to a new column. In this example it would be df[‘Colour']

```
+---+----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+--------+
|   |   SKU    |           Name           |         Description         | Category | Colour |
+---+----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+--------+
| 0 | 7E+10    | Red Lace Midi Dress      | Red Lace Midi D...          | Dresses  |        |
| 1 | 7E+10    | Long Armed Sweater Azure | Long Armed Sweater Azure... | Sweaters |        |
| 2 | 2,01E+08 | High Top Ruby Sneakers   | High Top Ruby Sneakers...   | Shoes    |        |
| 3 | 4,87E+10 | Tight Indigo Jeans       | Tight Indigo Jeans...       | Denim    |        |
| 4 | 2,2E+09  | T-Shirt Navy             | T-Shirt Navy...             | T-Shirts |        |
+---+----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+--------+
```

**Expected result:**

```
+---+----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+--------+
|   |   SKU    |           Name           |         Description         | Category | Colour |
+---+----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+--------+
| 0 | 7E+10    | Red Lace Midi Dress      | Red Lace Midi D...          | Dresses  | red    |
| 1 | 7E+10    | Long Armed Sweater Azure | Long Armed Sweater Azure... | Sweaters | blue   |
| 2 | 2,01E+08 | High Top Ruby Sneakers   | High Top Ruby Sneakers...   | Shoes    | red    |
| 3 | 4,87E+10 | Tight Indigo Jeans       | Tight Indigo Jeans...       | Denim    | blue   |
| 4 | 2,2E+09  | T-Shirt Navy             | T-Shirt Navy...             | T-Shirts | blue   |
+---+----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+--------+
```

My code:

```
colour = {'red': ('red', 'rose', 'ruby’), ‘blue’: (‘azure’, ‘indigo’, ’navy')}

def fetchColours(x):
    for key, value in colour.items():
            if value in x:
                return key
            else:
                return np.nan

df['Colour'] = df['Name'].apply(fetchColours)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

I can't run a tuple against string. How would I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through each value in the dictionary key tuple values.

As per the error message, you cannot check whether a `tuple` exists in a `str` type.

In addition, make sure your `else` statement occurs after the outer `for` loop, so that all keys are tested before you output the default value.

Finally, make sure you check versus `str.lower()`, since string matching is case sensitive in Python.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Red Lace Midi Dress', 'Long Armed Sweater Azure',
                            'High Top Ruby Sneakers', 'Tight Indigo Jeans',
                            'T-Shirt Navy']})

colour = {'red': ('red', 'rose', 'ruby'), 'blue': ('azure', 'indigo', 'navy')}

def fetchColours(x):
    for key, values in colour.items():
        for value in values:
            if value in x.lower():
                return key
    else:
        return np.nan

df['Colour'] = df['Name'].apply(fetchColours)
```

Result:

```
                       Name Colour
0       Red Lace Midi Dress    red
1  Long Armed Sweater Azure   blue
2    High Top Ruby Sneakers    red
3        Tight Indigo Jeans   blue
4              T-Shirt Navy   blue
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation, it works as excepted. Let's say that i had more than one value that matched the df['Name'] column.

Example: Blue and Red Lace Midi Dress. Would it be easy to store these in the same cell? (blue,red).

Comment: It's possible. I suggest you have a go yourself. If you get stuck, you can ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to search a tuple of words inside a string, while I guess you want to check if any word of the tuple is in the string.

BTW strings are case sensitive in python.

You could replace :

```
if value in x:
```

by

```
if any(word in x.lower() for word in value):
```